Проблема с нацеливанием проекта ASP.NET Core и установкой пакета Nuget
Я имею проект ASP, который сейчас использует .NET 6.0, это указано в .csproj.
Когда я пытаюсь добавить пакет Nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentification.JwtBearer Nuget выдаёт ошибку, которая говорит о том, что пакет не поддерживает .netcoreapp6.0 (.NETCoreApp Version=v6.0). Пакет поддерживает только .net6.0 (.NETFramework Version=v6.0).
Максимально странная ошибка, учитывая что NETFramework и NETCore уже давно не поддерживаются и не могут иметь 6 версии. Пользуюсь Rider 2020.1, но ошибка такая-же и при использовании dotnet CLI.
SDK стоит, MSBuild 17.0 версии.

Target Framework покажите https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks У вас скорее всего netcoreapp6.0 написано, а должно быть net6.0. Опечатка в .csproj файле.

@aepot нет, в файле .csproj указано .net6.0

покажите эту строчку

https://stackoverflow.com/q/71374503/12888024
